# Problem with mk4ht

Tags: miktex

I'm trying to compile my .tex file to html, suitable for conversion to an ebook. I'm using the following command:

```
C:\...\write-up>mk4ht htlatex diss.tex 'xhtml,charset=utf-8,pmathml' ' -cunihtf -utf8 -cvalidate'
```

But after a while I get the error message:

```
! I can't find file `'xhtml.cfg'.
<to be read again>
                   \relax
l.42 \begin{document}

Please type another input file name:
```

and I'm not sure what to do. What am I missing? I'm using MiKTeX on Windows 7.

Comment: Also: removing everything after `diss.tex` in the command gives the same error, but with `can't find file '.cfg'.`

Comment: Do double quotes in place of single quotes help?  See http://www.tug.org/applications/tex4ht/mn-commands.html